# CSS File not styling the text

Tags: html, css, django

I have been recently developing a website on Django and would like to use CSS for some basic stuff. As a test, i made a static dir, and all. And applied my css like this `h1 { color:blue }`. This works, but when i want to change the color to something like red, and I refresh the page, it doesnt work at all (It stays Blue). Any ideas on how to fix this? I loaded static like this on the HTML

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'WEBApp/style.css' %}">`

Comment: Disable cache in your browser dev tools and ensure that you’re not reading the cached CSS file. Also inspect the CSS file loaded by the browser to verify that it is indeed the updated version.

Comment: don't edit from the file that corrected just edit in the one which is not static or edit in both

Comment: Thank you so much, that definitely worked. The browser was indeed reading the cached version, which is kinda weird. But Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

Replace `{% static 'WEBApp/style.css' %}` with the CSS file name, or, if it is in a different folder, do the entire file address.

Comment: Don't explain why this would work, gives an answer to something that has nothing to do with the question, doesn't address the actual issue at all. This was a caching issue, the stylesheet was clearly being loaded properly like OP addressed. Couldn't have been more clearly a caching issue.